# HQL select with complicated condition

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

The method in Hibernate repository:

```
@Query(value = "FROM Ticket WHERE t.id =: ticketId AND (sender =: user OR recipient := user)")
Optional<Ticket> findByIdAndSenderAndRecipient(@NotNull Long ticketId, User user);
```

But IntelliJ is sad about the wrong syntax. How to fix this HQL query correctly?

UPDATE_1

```
@Query(value = "SELECT count(t) FROM Ticket t WHERE t.status = 'NEW' AND (t.sender =: user OR t.recipient =: user)")
Integer countNewTickets(@NotNull User user);
```

And get error:

> 2021-08-06 21:14:17.777  WARN 6760 --- [qtp350607671-33]
> org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel     : /api/profile/tickets/count
>
> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
> processing failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException:
> org.hibernate.QueryException: Named parameter not bound : user; nested
> exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
> org.hibernate.QueryException: Named parameter not bound : user    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]  at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]  at
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:517)
> ~[jakarta.servlet-api-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]  at
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:584)
> ~[jakarta.servlet-api-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]    at
> org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:799)
> ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.42.v20210604.jar:9.4.42.v20210604]    at
> org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
> ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.42.v20210604.jar:9.4.42.v20210604]    at
> org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:228)
> ~[websocket-server-9.4.42.v20210604.jar:9.4.42.v20210604]     at
> org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
> ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.42.v20210604.jar:9.4.42.v20210604]    at
> org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
> ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.42.v20210604.jar:9.4.42.v20210604]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)
> ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
> ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
> ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
> ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:121)
> ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
> ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
> ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
> ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
> ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
> ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:105)
> ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
> ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
> ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
> ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
> ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
> ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]    at
> com.tradeshare.config.jwt.JwtTokenFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtTokenFilter.java:38)
> ~[classes/:na]    at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]     at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
> ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
> ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
> ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
> ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]    at
> org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]     at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]     at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
> ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
> ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
> ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]    at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]     at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
> ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
> ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
> ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
> ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
> ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]    at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]     at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
> ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
> ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
> ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]    at
> org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]     at
> org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]     at
> org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
> ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.42.v20210604.jar:9.4.42.v20210604]    at
> org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
> ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.42.v20210604.jar:9.4.42.v20210604]    at
> org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]     at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]     at
> org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
> ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.42.v20210604.jar:9.4.42.v20210604]    at
> org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
> ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.42.v20210604.jar:9.4.42.v20210604]    at
> org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]     at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]     at
> org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
> ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.42.v20210604.jar:9.4.42.v20210604]    at
> org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
> ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.42.v20210604.jar:9.4.42.v20210604]    at
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96)
> ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]   at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]     at
> org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
> ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.42.v20210604.jar:9.4.42.v20210604]    at
> org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
> ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.42.v20210604.jar:9.4.42.v20210604]    at
> org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]     at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]     at
> org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
> ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.42.v20210604.jar:9.4.42.v20210604]    at
> org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
> ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.42.v20210604.jar:9.4.42.v20210604]    at
> org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:548)
> ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.42.v20210604.jar:9.4.42.v20210604]    at
> org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
> ~[jetty-server-9.4.42.v20210604.jar:9.4.42.v20210604]     at
> org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:602)
> ~[jetty-security-9.4.42.v20210604.jar:9.4.42.v20210604]   at
> org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
> ~[jetty-server-9.4.42.v20210604.jar:9.4.42.v20210604]     at
> org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
> ~[jetty-server-9.4.42.v20210604.jar:9.4.42.v20210604]     at
> org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)
> ~[jetty-server-9.4.42.v20210604.jar:9.4.42.v20210604]     at
> org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
> ~[jetty-server-9.4.42.v20210604.jar:9.4.42.v20210604]     at
> org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1435)
> ~[jetty-server-9.4.42.v20210604.jar:9.4.42.v20210604]     at
> org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
> ~[jetty-server-9.4.42.v20210604.jar:9.4.42.v20210604]     at
> org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)
> ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.42.v20210604.jar:9.4.42.v20210604]    at
> org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)
> ~[jetty-server-9.4.42.v20210604.jar:9.4.42.v20210604]     at
> org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
> ~[jetty-server-9.4.42.v20210604.jar:9.4.42.v20210604]     at
> org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1350)
> ~[jetty-server-9.4.42.v20210604.jar:9.4.42.v20210604]     at
> org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
> ~[jetty-server-9.4.42.v20210604.jar:9.4.42.v20210604]     at
> org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
> ~[jetty-server-9.4.42.v20210604.jar:9.4.42.v20210604]     at
> org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
> ~[jetty-server-9.4.42.v20210604.jar:9.4.42.v20210604]     at
> org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:388)
> ~[jetty-server-9.4.42.v20210604.jar:9.4.42.v20210604]     at
> org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:633)
> ~[jetty-server-9.4.42.v20210604.jar:9.4.42.v20210604]     at
> org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:380)
> ~[jetty-server-9.4.42.v20210604.jar:9.4.42.v20210604]     at
> org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
> ~[jetty-server-9.4.42.v20210604.jar:9.4.42.v20210604]     at
> org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
> ~[jetty-io-9.4.42.v20210604.jar:9.4.42.v20210604]     at
> org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
> ~[jetty-io-9.4.42.v20210604.jar:9.4.42.v20210604]     at
> org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
> ~[jetty-io-9.4.42.v20210604.jar:9.4.42.v20210604]     at
> org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:338)
> ~[jetty-util-9.4.42.v20210604.jar:9.4.42.v20210604]   at
> org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:315)
> ~[jetty-util-9.4.42.v20210604.jar:9.4.42.v20210604]   at
> org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:173)
> ~[jetty-util-9.4.42.v20210604.jar:9.4.42.v20210604]   at
> org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:137)
> ~[jetty-util-9.4.42.v20210604.jar:9.4.42.v20210604]   at
> org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:882)
> ~[jetty-util-9.4.42.v20210604.jar:9.4.42.v20210604]   at
> org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1036)
> ~[jetty-util-9.4.42.v20210604.jar:9.4.42.v20210604]   at
> java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) ~[na:na] Caused by:
> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException:
> org.hibernate.QueryException: Named parameter not bound : user; nested
> exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
> org.hibernate.QueryException: Named parameter not bound : user    at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:374)
> ~[spring-orm-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]     at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:235)
> ~[spring-orm-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]     at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551)
> ~[spring-orm-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]     at
> org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
> ~[spring-tx-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]  at
> org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
> ~[spring-tx-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]  at
> org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)
> ~[spring-tx-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]  at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]     at
> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:145)
> ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]    at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]     at
> org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]     at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]     at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]     at
> jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy147.countNewTickets(Unknown Source)
> ~[na:na]  at
> com.tradeshare.service.TicketServiceImpl.countNewTickets(TicketServiceImpl.java:41)
> ~[classes/:na]    at
> com.tradeshare.service.TicketServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$9080a1ca.invoke()
> ~[na:na]  at
> org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
> ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]    at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]     at
> com.tradeshare.service.TicketServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$363910dd.countNewTickets()
> ~[na:na]  at
> com.tradeshare.controller.TicketController.countNewTickets(TicketController.java:42)
> ~[classes/:na]    at
> com.tradeshare.controller.TicketController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$70106294.invoke()
> ~[na:na]  at
> org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
> ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]    at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:779)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]     at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]     at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]     at
> org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:61)
> ~[spring-security-core-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]   at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]     at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]     at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:692)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]     at
> com.tradeshare.controller.TicketController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ea8faba7.countNewTickets()
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
> at
> org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]     at
> org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]     at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]  at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]  at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]  at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]  at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1063)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]  at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]  at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]  ... 96 common frames omitted Caused
> by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException:
> Named parameter not bound : user  at
> org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:138)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1659)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]   at
> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:196)
> ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]    at
> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88)
> ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]    at
> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:155)
> ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]    at
> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:143)
> ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]    at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]    at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]    at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:159)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]    at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]    at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]     at
> org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]    at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]     at
> org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
> ~[spring-tx-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]  at
> org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
> ~[spring-tx-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]  at
> org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
> ~[spring-tx-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]  at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]     at
> org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
> ~[spring-tx-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]  ... 132 common frames omitted Caused by:
> org.hibernate.QueryException: Named parameter not bound : user    at
> org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingsImpl.verifyParametersBound(QueryParameterBindingsImpl.java:211)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.beforeQuery(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1496)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1602)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1652)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]   ... 148 common frames
> omitted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Colons must be set at the beginning of parameters:

```
FROM Ticket WHERE t.id = :ticketId AND (sender = :user OR recipient = :user)
```

Comment: Update question

Comment: Done. Problem was in `=: user` to `= :user` at all. Thank you for your help.